# What is an equivalent expression for "having the moon across" (Italian)?

Tags: phrase-request

When somebody is nervous, or easily irritable, in Italian you would say *avere la luna di traverso* which Google Translate translates with "have the moon across." (It seems Google Translate gives the literal translation, rather than an equivalent expression.)

I looked for any expression using *moon*, but I found is *over the moon* which has the opposite meaning of what I am trying to say, and *moon* used as verb, in phrases similar to "lying in bed eating candy, mooning around" for which I cannot say if it is said in a positive way, or a negative way.

Another, similar expression used in Italian is *avere un diavolo per capello*, which Google Translate translates as "have a devil for hair."

Is there an equivalent expression I could use in this case?

Comment: What does "having the moon" represent? For example "over the moon" implies you are high, i.e. happy. *Across* could be interpreted as *sideways* or *askance*, as well, according Google Translate.

Comment: [Word Reference](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/avere%20la%20luna%20di%20traverso) gives the option "got up on the wrong side of bed".

Comment: _Avere_ ("to have"), and _essere_ ("to be") are verbs normally used in Italian, and they are also auxiliary verbs. For example, "I am asleep" becomes _io ho sonno_ (literally, "I have sleep [noun]"), and "I am hungry" becomes _io ho fame" (literally, "I have hungriness").

Comment: @tchrist What I meant when I said "another, similar expression" is that _avere un diavolo per capello_ means the same as _avere la luna di traverso_: When you use one, you could use the other.

Comment: @tchrist I was replying to Matt Ellen, since he asked what "having the moon" represent. Also, I have said when _avere la luna di traverso_ is used.

Comment: So you just want an idiom that means someone is uneasy about something, or touchy, or prickly, or quick to anger?  Do you want one of these odd idiomatic phrases that must be explained to be understood, or would a simple word suffice?

Comment: so "I have the moon" means "I am the moon"? So "I am the sideways moon"? But what does being or having the moon mean metaphorically?

Comment: @MattEllen No, _avere la luna_ is not the same as _essere la luna_. (These phrases are the respective translations of the English phrases you used.) I wrongly understood you were asking why it's _avere la luna_, with _to have_, and not another verb. _Avere_ is one of those Italian verbs with many meanings, and it is not only used for possession. As per why _the moon_, I guess that, astrologically, having the moon in your zodiacal sign is considered a negative influence for your mood.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Does this phrase mean that someone is *always* irritable, or just happens to be irritable right now?

Comment: @WendiKidd If it is not differently specified, the person is irritable in that moment.

Comment: By the way, I think it's **much** more common *avere la luna storta*, which has the same meaning. At least, in friuli I **never** heard someone using *di traverso* in this phrase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you specified in comments that the phrase refers to someone who is irritable at a given moment, not in general, I think what you're looking for is this:

> -Person A does or says something that makes others feel he is being irritable and grumpy/rude.
>
> -Person B: "Looks like someone ***got up on the wrong side of the bed this morning***."

The phrase seems to be similar in meaning to your original Italian expression.  The basic idea is that someone is acting uncharacteristically rude or grumpy, and others are surprised by and unhappy with this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the words anxious, cranky, grumpy.

Answer (score 2):

A coarse expression that conveys this sentiment is "to have a hair across one's ass." It describes someone who is in a generally irritable or "pissy" mood, and can be used both for someone who tends to have that kind of disposition as well as someone who is just having an angry day.

It doesn't have the connotation of nervousness though. "Having one's panties in a knot" or "knickers in a twist" is similar, slightly less coarse, and also implies that the person is high-strung and possibly over-reacting to the situation.

None of these is suitable for polite company however.

Answer (score 1):

[Moonstruck](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moonstruck) (not the 'in love' kind) seems to have some of the sentiments you are trying to capture.  It's not as close as jittery or high-strung in definition, but closer metaphorically.

Answer (score 0):

Try *[high-strung](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/high-strung), edgy, restless, tense, agitated, antsy, distraught, frantic.*

If you give some more context, I could suggest something more narrowly matching your request as these all have different connotations.

Definitely avoid using *moon* as a verb. The most common usage of *mooning someone* means showing them your naked butt.

Answer (score 0):

Synonyms for *nervous*: *[be] jittery, [have] the jitters, [have] butterflies in [my] stomach, [be] uptight*

Synonyms for *easily irritable*: *[be] moody, [be] uptight, [be] irritable, [be] grouchy, to have a short fuse, [be] cantankerous, [be] crabby*.

There are probably many other synonyms.  The only term I can think of that means both nervous and easily irritable is *uptight*.

Answer (score 0):

The moon is sometimes associated with making people "crazy." (Hence the references to a "lunatic" or a "looney" person.)

The Italian phrase roughly translates into: "The moon has a hold of him." He's  acting rather "erratically."

An equivalent (colloquial)  English expression might be: "He's got ants in his pants."